# Iptables Captive Portal Redirect http but allow https Pass Through

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, redirection

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/A-Grey-Hat/) to create an Access Point that redirects all http requests to my local served web page.

However https requests, due to certificate errors, do not get my page and instead act like they are loading for eternity.

**I would like to create a kind of walled garden that allows https requests to access the internet but redirects http requests to my page since users are bound to click an http link after a while.**

I am using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian lite which is basically the same as Debian. Apache2 serves the web page, dnsmasq handles dhcp, and hostapd to create the access point.

**/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=FreeWiFi
channel=6
```

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
address=/#/10.0.0.1
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10, 10.0.0.250,12h
no-resolv
log-queries
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface wlan0 inet static address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 255.0.0.0
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

**IP Tables Rules Created**

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -j DROP
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

I am assuming I need to add another rule for port 443 to allow https requests. I am not sure how I should finish setting up dnsmasq and how to forward the trafic to my hardware connection eth0.

**EDIT:** Looking around it seems I might not need to change anything in dnsmasq but I just need to use some iptable rules to reroute https trafic to eth0? I do not know how to do that specifically for https requests though.

**sudo iptables -nvL**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 491 packets, 45444 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/24                  tcp multiport dports 80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/24                  tcp multiport dports 80

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 413 packets, 52820 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                    tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                    tcp dpt:443
```

**sudo iptables-save**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Mar  7 22:56:30 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1781:191954]
:INPUT ACCEPT [704:143612]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [204:15231]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [219:16055]
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Mar  7 22:56:30 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Mar  7 22:56:30 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [389:44149]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [84:3648]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [376:86142]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Mar  7 22:56:30 2017
```

Comment: "https requests, due to certificate errors, do not get my page and instead act like they are loading for eternity" – that's just firewall configuration; if it actually was a certificate error you'd be getting a Big Red Error Message from the browser.

Comment: @grawity Ok that makes sense...Im having trouble with getting the correct firewall config to enable it to pass through though.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -d 192.168.2.2/32 -j ACCEPT --dports 80

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -i wlan0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2 --dports 80
```

The first rule accepts encrypted traffic, and will be considered established on the return traffic.

Comment: This looks like it will work!! But for the ip address do I use 10.0.0.1 which is the ip address I set in /etc/network/interfaces? So like for the second line 10.0.0.1/24 and for the third line 10.0.0.1?

Comment: When I ran the commands with 10.0.0.1/24 and 10.0.0.1 for the IP address the first 2 commands gave no errors but the last command said  `You must specify '--match-set' with proper arguments`

Comment: sorry I made a copy and paste error. fixed.  I took out the -m set.  The IP address is where non-encrypted web traffic goes.

Comment: Got that error out of the way but now it says `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.` Should I add -t nat to the last command...I read that somewhere but I don't know if it applies.

Comment: Ok I had the wrong interface on the 3rd line, which line say no chain/target/match?

Comment: Its The 3rd line.

Comment: I rebooted and cleared all rules except those listed in my question(besides the ACCEPT 80 one) However, when I run the first line it says `Can't use -i with OUTPUT`. If I change it to INPUT the command runs but https requests are not able to pass through. The second line with run fine and I am using 10.0.0.1/24. The third line will run if I add -t nat but I am not sure if that is right.

Comment: add correct you need -o instead sorry.

Comment: in the last line I add -t nat right?

Comment: yes, that referrs to the NAT table.

Comment: I applied those rules and now https requests say "Problem loading page...unable to connect". Http requests are still redirected to my server like they should be. Do you think dnsmasq might be conflicting with iptables? In the log I see that it tried to redirect me when I typed https://www.facebook.com to my local server. But it seems it should give  a certificate error and not say it just wasnt able to load the page. Sorry if that was too wordy.

Comment: post an iptables-save   so I can see all your rules.

Comment: Ok I posted it and iptables -nvL in the question.

Comment: every iptables needs related/established as part of the rule set.  I have added one, try that.

Comment: I tried but it still does not work for https...do you think that this may have to do with dnsmasq trying to redirect everything to my local server. Maybe its trying to redirect the https requests too?

Comment: iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

Comment: no luck same issue :( See updated iptables-save in question. Maybe the order of the rules affects it?

Comment: **cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward**        what is the result of this command a 1 or 0

Comment: Yes just checked and it is 1 enabled.